# If you can make $30$ biscuits with $230$ grams of self raising flour, how many can you make with $1$ kg?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If you can make $30$ biscuits with $230$ grams of self raising flour, how many can you make with $1$ kg?

I've worked out you can make $120$ with $920$ grams, but I don't know how many more you can make with $80$ grams, how do I work this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You find out how many biscuits you can make with one gram. You have 
$$\frac{30 \text{ biscuits}}{230 \text{ grams}}=\frac{3}{23} \text{biscuits per gram}$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: no, sorry im not intelligent enough to work it out from there, so are you saying it takes 23 grams to make one biscuit?

Comment: @greg No, I'm saying that you can make 3/23 biscuits with a single gram. If you had 23 grams, you'd be able to make 3 biscuits.

Comment: ok, not sure if ive worked it out correctly but is the correct answer 130biscuits?

Comment: @greg Yes, good job!

Answer (score 1):

This is just a simple proportion.

$$ \frac{30 \text{ biscuits}}{230 \text{ grams}} = \frac{? \text{ biscuits}}{1000 \text{ grams}} $$

Now lets represent $ ? \space \text{biscuits} $ with $ x $.

$$ \frac{30}{230} = \frac{x}{1000} $$

Now cross multiply...

$$ (30)(1000) = (230)(x) $$

And just work it out...

$$ 30000 = 230x $$

$$ \frac{30000}{230} = x $$

$$ \frac{3000}{23} = x $$

$$ x \approx 130.4348 $$

Comment: You can make the text in math environments look nicer by using \text{}.

Comment: Oh! Thanks! I was wondering how you did that.

Comment: $3000/23= 130.4348$...

Comment: @AdityaDeSaha Shush, it's a Monday.